# Point to point connection not using full bandwith

Tags: networking, network-share, vlan

Here's my network:

[A]<------20 Mbit point to point ---------->[B]<-------20 Mbit point to point-------------->[C]

At [A] there's a switch, at [C] there's another switch, while at [B] there's a router which manages 4 virtual lans.
For each of the lans, a switch is used to connect about 50 workstations.
Those clients (workstations) are sited at [A] and [B] but not [C].
And using point to point and vlan schema, [A] and [B] share one vlan (a switch on [A] is connected to another switch on [B] both are connected to the same router vlan.
That's the basic schema of my network.
Let's suppose I have to retrieve a large amount of data from a server sited in [C], from [A] and from [B].
And let's also suppose that there's another fileserver at [B] where client on [B] and [A] retrieve data.
Let's also suppose that I can download from [A] to [B] at full speed (20 Mbit) and from [B] to [C] at full speed (20 Mbit) but I can't (no way) from [A] to [C].
What could be the problem? Can you help me or address me to some supposed solutions?
A test showed errors when the instrument was connected to the switch, but no problems at all when the point to point was connected directly.

Comment: "A test showed errors when the instrument was connected to the switch" - what test showed what errors on what switch? how much bandwidth are you getting and what do you consider "full bandwidth"?

Comment: PtP protocols involve encapsulating packets, you WILL need to tune your MTU and MSS to get the best throughput on tunnels like that..